# How can I find TRUE - FALSE situations in C (2^n situations need to write)

Tags: python, c, probability

I want to write a program which shows combinations of True and False. This is only one part of program. I wrote other parts but I can't find a solution to this.

For example :

```
input: 2
output:
    T T
    T F
    F T
    F F

input: 4
output:
    T T T T 
    T T T F 
    T T F T 
    T T F F 
    T F T T 
    T F T F 
    T F F T 
    T F F F 
    F T T T 
    F T T F 
    F T F T 
    F T F F 
    F F T T 
    F F T F 
    F F F T 
    F F F F
```

If you don't want to write code, you can explain or use pseudo-code or Python :)

Comment: Second example is wrong: the n equals to four, while the number of T[F] letters in every block is 5.

Comment: you are right i edited

Comment: So you want to learn how to display binary with True/False arrays? What pseudo-code do you have so far?

Comment: I wrote other parts of homework. Other part do calculation with this array. (-(-(T&T)|(-(T|-T)) for example. I am thinking about the this part a day. I couldn't find any algorithm for it in my mind.

Comment: do you want the output printed with a '/' after each line or a list?

Comment: no in editor mod it shows there is no space because of that i put them.

Comment: do you want a list of all combos or to print the output?

Comment: Since you tagged your question with C aswell: [Link](https://eval.in/150002).

Comment: Thank you my man. I want C code instead of python. I wrote python because it is like psudo. But site don't understand me :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about simple conversion of integers to binary format?

```
def possibilities(bitcount):
    for i in reversed(xrange(2**bitcount)):
        yield ("{0:0" + str(bitcount) + "b}").format(i)

def prettyprint(bitcount):
    for p in possibilities(bitcount):
        print " ".join(p.replace("0", "F").replace("1", "T") + "/")
```

If you need to process the possibilities programatically, a bunch of bit operations will be enough and you don't even need the string conversion.

Comment: This will print None at the end as you are not returning anything.

Comment: @Danastahr, I know what a generator is, your prettyprint is not a generator.

Comment: why do you need a function to print it out?

Comment: The point is, if you were inputting the code to a grader , it would be marked as incorrect as there would be an extra "None" printed out.

Comment: sorry +1, side effect of getting two hours sleep and printing function instead of calling it!

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: No problem, I'm also sorry for being a bit impolite. I was pretty sure that I'm right :).

Comment: @Danastahr, no worries it was my mistake ;)

Answer (score 2):

There you go:

```
def PrintTruthTable(size):
    for i in range(0,1<<size):
        print ' '.join(['T' if (i>>j)&1==1 else 'F' for j in range(0,size)])
```

- The `i` index iterates through every possible combination between 0 and 2^size-1
- The `j` index iterates through every bit in the combination given by the value of `i`

---

This might be easier for you to understand:

```
def PrintTruthTable(size):
    for i in range(0,1<<size):
        line = ''
        for j in range(0,size):
            if (i>>j)&1 == 1:
                line += 'T'
            else:
                line += 'F'
        print line
```

Comment: Can you little explain this part for j in range(0,size) why it is at the end.

Comment: @user3223986: See updated answer with a Python code that might be easier for you to understand...

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do so would be using binary code.

We will simply write the **binary codes** for all numbers from 0 to the ***maximum number*** we can make using the ***number of binary digits*** equal to the input.

Say, we input 3.
The maximum number we can make using 3 binary digits, is 111 i.e. 7.
So we will write binary code for all number from 0 to 7.

Which are:

000=0

001=1

010=2

011=3

100=4

101=5

110=6

111=7

To write T or F, we will simply put a condition where T is printed for 1 and F for 0.

Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int num_of_digits;

void bitcode(int num){
    int current_digit_num=num_of_digits;
while(current_digit_num!=0){
    if(num%2==1)
        printf("T ");
    else
        printf("F ");
    num=num/2;
    current_digit_num--;
}
}

main()
{
    int current_num,value;
scanf("%d", &num_of_digits);
value=pow(2,num_of_digits);
for(current_num=0;current_num<value;current_num++){
    bitcode(current_num);
    printf("\n");
}
return 0;
}
```

NOTE: This method works because from 0 (000..) to the maximum number (111..), we go through all the possible combinations we can make to fill that much number of digits with 0 or 1.